# Teste unitário de uma pesquisa SQL no Junit

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer o teste unitário no Junit.

Como faço o @Test do método abaixo:

```
public static StringBuilder findSQLPA() {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" select  fi1.co_carteira as carteira, ");
    sql.append("  fi1.nu_cpf_cnpj as cpf_cnpj, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.co_fundo_siart as siart, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.no_fundo as fundo,   ");
    sql.append(" fi1.no_cotista as cotista, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.nu_operacao_conta as op, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.nu_conta as conta,  ");
    sql.append(" fi1.dt_mvtco_antiga as dt_antiga, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.dt_mvtco_recente as dt_recente, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.pc_taxa_administracao as taxa, ");
    sql.append(" fd.no_tipo_macro_fundo as tipo_fundo, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.vr_saldo_bruto,    ");
    sql.append(" fi1.vr_saldo_liquido, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.vr_potencial_mes, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.vr_pontecial_ano, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.vr_potencial_12m , ");
    sql.append(" fi1.nu_unidade_dire as dire, ");
    sql.append(" fi1.nu_unidade_sr as sr,   ");
    sql.append(" fi1.nu_unidade as age  ");
    sql.append(" from cfism001.cfitb001_fundo_investimento fi1 ");
    sql.append(" inner join cfism001.cfitb007_resumo_cliente fi ");
    sql.append(" on fi.nu_cpf_cnpj = fi1.nu_cpf_cnpj  ");
    sql.append(" and fi.nu_unidade_dire = fi1.nu_unidade_dire ");
    sql.append(" and fi.nu_unidade_sr = fi1.nu_unidade_sr ");
    sql.append(" and fi.nu_unidade = fi1.nu_unidade ");
    sql.append(" and fi.dt_importacao = fi1.dt_importacao ");
    sql.append("   left join icosm001.icotbu24_unidade u ");
    sql.append(" on (fi1.nu_unidade = u.nu_unidade AND u.dt_fim is null AND u.ic_ultima_situacao = 'AT') ");
    sql.append(" left join  cfism001.cfitb002_tipo_macro_fundo fd     ");
    sql.append(" on (fi1.co_tipo_macro_fundo = fd.co_tipo_macro_fundo) ");
    sql.append(" where fi1.dt_importacao = :dt_importacao  and fi1.nu_unidade = :nu_unidade  @filtro ");
    return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testes que envolvem consulta ao banco de dados não são chamados de testes unitários. Estes tipos de testes são chamados de **testes de integração**, embora não necessariamente apenas os testes de integração testem o banco de dados (testes funcionais, por exemplo, também o fazem).

Testes de integração são complicados de se fazer sem a ajuda de algum framework, pois seu teste vai envolver a criação (ou uso) de um banco de dados para o teste, de uma conexão JDBC, preparar os dados a serem consultados, chamar o método da classe que faz a consulta, etc.

Usando um framework para este teste facilita muito. No Spring, por exemplo, um teste do seu SQL ficaria algo como:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class FundoInvestimentoRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private FundoInvestimentoRepository repository; //o SQL seu estaria implementado dentro de um método do FundoInvestimentoRepository

    public void testarConsulta() {

        repository.inserir(new FundoInvestimento("1", "23456")); //valores fictícios para dar um INSERT no banco de dados e consultá-los

        FundoInvestimentoVO fundoVO = repository.consultar();
        assertEquals("23456", fundoVO.getConta());
    }

}
```

Comment: primeiramene obrigado pelo retorno. Vejo que o pessoal comenta do framework Mockito. Você conhece?

Comment: Conheço sim. O Mockito é um framework bem robusto usado largamente pelo framework do Spring para testes de integração, inclusive. Mas ele sozinho, para o teste que quer fazer, é só uma ferramenta auxiliar. O "grosso" de um teste de integração é um framework como o Spring que faz. Aqui explica um pouco sobre os vários tipos de testes de integração e como o Mockito aparece no meio deles: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing